# How to log timestamp in a different cell when a cell has a specific value?

Tags: excel, vba, timestamp, auto

I want to log timestamp in a cell when a specific value comes automatically and delete the timestamp when the cell doesn't have the value anymore.

Example
If a cell in a range (X14:X70) contains "Done" or "Skip" from a dropbox, then I want timestamp to appear in the cell in different column BB.

And If the cell does not have the values anymore, I also want the timestamp to disappear.

timestamp format to be yyyy.mm.dd

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

In cel `BB14` put this formula down:

`=IF(OR(X14="Done",X14="Skip"),NOW(),"")`

Drag down the formula and format your column with custom format `yyyy.mm.dd`

Or when you dont want to manually format the column:

`=IF(OR(X14="Done",X14="Skip"),TEXT(NOW(),"yyyy.mm.dd"),"")`

Comment: Thank you !  I did not even realize I could have used only excel formula instead of VBA.

Comment: No problem @SunghwanPark, if this has answered your question, please consider to mark it as answered.